# flowchart connectors between user controls in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, xaml, flowchart

I'm trying to make connecting paths between various user controls, possibly with multiple connections emerging from a single user control, and preferably paths composed of only horizontal and vertical elements.  I haven't been able to figure out a good way to do this exclusively in xaml, especially if the user controls span different panels (ie stackpanels and wrappanels) for formatting reasons.  Has anyone found a good free solution, or have a good suggestion of how to make my own?

Comment: Are you talking on like a static fixed layout, or created dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at Sukram's series: http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/MemberArticles.aspx?amid=65924

Although this is for WPF, most of it can easily be ported to Silverlight.

Note that for the routing of the connections - in your case this is called 'orthogonal routing', this may require more sophisticated solutions, depending on your exact usecase.

Of course there are commercial solutions available for Silverlight that can do this. For [yFiles](http://www.yworks.com/yfilessilverlight) there are online demos available that show the edge routing capabilities in action. This library (as most good implementations) allows for using any Silverlight controls as 'nodes'. The organziation chart demo under the above link shows this capability nicely. *Disclaimer*: I work for the company that created the above mentioned commercial library, however on Stackoverflow I do not represent my employer.